# How can I listen to back/forward button click in my SPA?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browser-history, html5-history

I have a Backbone app, it uses Backbone.history.start({pushState: true}). I render pages based on URL change, back and forward buttons work just fine, views are rendered well.

There is a problem though, page scroll positions are't kept when you click back or forward button. It makes it feel very bad.

I thought I would keep an array of pages visited and I would store scroll position for each of them. Then I would listen if user click back/forward and I would load appropriate scroll position.

But.

I just found out I am unable to tell when user click a back or forward button. If I could, I would just read stored scroll position of previous page and apply it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the scroll location as a part of the route, using something like:

```
router.navigate('/my/route/scroll/[my_scroll_location]', {replace: true});
```

so It won't add a new history point, but will modify the current one. this way, when you hit "back" it will go to the previous "page"/route, and then hitting "forward" have enough information to scroll to the right point.

Comment: This might work but I dont like like the idea to store scroll position in the URL. I would like to keep it on the object and then if back button was clicked I would like to read it form the object. I am still wondering around it so if I wont be able to do it my way, I will have to do it your way. Thx